# wordpress unable to upload image, however some images get uploaded

Tags: wordpress

I am unable to upload image in wordpress but sometime image gets uploaded.
I checked whether it is issue with image size more surprisingly sometimes i am able to upload higher size image and sometime not.

While uploading, in browser developer console it shows

````
Request URL: http://srintimates.com/wp-admin/async-upload.php
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 404 Not Found
Remote Address: 107.180.44.152:80
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin```

However the file http://srintimates.com/wp-admin/async-upload.php is there in server.
````

Answer (score 0):

Check your server is are space to upload ?

And what is the message you see in front `wp-admin`

Your question is unclear